# jquery menu recommendation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking for a jquery ui menu/submenu where I can easily add and bind "item" to any js function without having to have a html markup in advance (sth like [jjmenu](http://jursza.net/dev/jjmenu/)). I've for example looked at [superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) but I do not see how to easily bind items to functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read below if you really like superfish.

---

Did you try removing superfish from existing menu, adjusting your menu item, then reattaching superfish to it? It doesn't look like superfish has a "destroy" method, but you can user `jQuery.clone(false)` (on the menu box), insert the clone right next to existing menu, remove existing menu, attach superfish on new menu. Something like:

```
// given this:
var menu = $("ul.menu");
menu.superfish();

var newMenu = menu.clone(false); // false to not copy data/events (superfish)
newMenu.hide(); // just to minimize potential flicker
newMenu.superfish(); // new menu still not visible; if superfish shows it, then do:
newMenu.superfish().hide();

newMenu.insertAfter(menu);
menu.remove(); // this removes html and any events/data associated with it.
newMenu.show();
```